# Failed to instantiate module ngMaterial in mean stack

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, meanjs

I am using mean js. am a newbie in angular and mean js .I have replaced angular bootstrap with angular material.
Heres a copy of my bower.json:

```
{
  "name": "meanjs",     
  "description": "Full-Stack JavaScript with MongoDB, Express, AngularJS, and Node.js",
  "dependencies": {
     "angular": "~1.3",   
     "angular-resource": "~1.3",
     "angular-animate": "~1.3",
     "angular-messages": "~1.3",
     "angular-mocks": "~1.3",
     "angular-ui-notification": "~0.2.0",
     "angular-ui-router": "~0.2.10",
     "ng-file-upload": "~12.1.0",
     "angular-material": "0.7.1",
     "owasp-password-strength-test": "~1.3.0"
  }
}
```

Heres the console error message: 
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module ngMaterial due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'ngMaterial' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.

Angular config.js file:

```
'use strict';

  var applicationModuleName = 'mean';

  var service = {
    applicationEnvironment: window.env,
    applicationModuleName: applicationModuleName,
    applicationModuleVendorDependencies: ['ngResource', 'ngMessages', 
    'ui.router', 'ngFileUpload', 'ui-notification','ngMaterial'],
    registerModule: registerModule
  };
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take a moment to read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

My guess is you updated the bower.json but didn't run a new `bower install` command to pull down the library into your bower components folder.

If you look in there so you see an angular material folder?

Comment: No i had already installed .angular material folder insider the bower_components..My code is put it in the github . please look at here https://github.com/sreyas/mean